# Creating counter down using stopwatch [C#]

Tags: c#, timer, stopwatch

i want to create counter down, example every 10seconds, program will calling a method for doing the task. Before i used System.Windows.Forms.Timer and System.Timers.Timer, but i get inaccurate counting. Then i try to use System.Diagnostics.Timer i have read that this feature is very accurate.
This is my sample code

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
private bool StartTrue = false;
...
private void StartProg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

StartTrue = true;
StartCounting();
}

private void StartCounting()
{
while(StartTrue)
{
stopWatch.Start();
while(stopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds < 1);
stopWatch.Stop();
stopWatch.Reset();
...
// this part the program for doing task every x second
}
}
```

And i get my program hang, the cpu usage is high. Where is my mistake sir? Or what is the better way to do like this?

Update:
example i want to write data to serial every 10 seconds. When i used winform timer or system.timers

```
10  2/6/2015 6:24:34 PM
9  2/6/2015 6:24:35 PM
8  2/6/2015 6:24:36 PM
7  2/6/2015 6:24:37 PM
6  2/6/2015 6:24:38 PM
5  2/6/2015 6:24:39 PM
4  2/6/2015 6:24:40 PM
3  2/6/2015 6:24:41 PM
2  2/6/2015 6:24:42 PM
1  2/6/2015 6:24:44 PM
10  2/6/2015 6:24:45 PM
```

the timer tick is inaccurate, above, the lastline is when timer fires at sec 80.

Comment: You need to use a timer.

Comment: `while(stopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds < 1);` says, in essence, dedicate the CPU to asking "Are we there yet?" Windows does not provide guaranteed response time, so you need to define what accuracy you need. Even using a stopwatch you are at the mercy of higher priority tasks.

Comment: but timer is inaccurate sir.
i have test it before

Comment: @HABO : when the CPU asking "Are we there yet?", i think the CPU does nothing, is that a problem? i will edit my question, wait a minutes

Comment: Your `while` loop instructs the CPU to check the passage of time as quickly as possible. It will consume one processor core completely. If you had it [`Sleep`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for a few milliseconds between checks then the CPU usage would drop considerably.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Stopwatch` alone to measure time is inefficient as you need to either run [busy wait](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) or waste thread resource on `Thread.Sleep`. While busy wait may be necessary for short (10ms?) intervals your case (10s) does not seem to require that.

Have timer with much higher frequency than you need to perform the task and check if "the right time" comes. I.e. 100ms timer is probably more than enough to get reasonable "every 10 seconds" event.

From theoretical point of view you need frequency set in such a way so you have at least 2 checks inside margin of error: i.e. if you need 10s +/- 0.1s your timer should trigger at least every 0.1s / 2 = 0.05s. If you want to do fancy sampling - run timer with variable intervals - 9s, 0.1s, 0.01s close you get to desired time. You can read proper explanation starting from [Nyquist–Shannon sampling theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem).

Note that Window is not [Real-Time-Operating-System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system) and does not make any guarantees for any particular thread to be given chance to execute at particular moment of time (even for threads with higher priority). So you should expect relatively large error (I'd start with 30-50ms estimate on relatively free system) for most time related operation unless special care is taken to minimize that. Again for 10s interval it is probably not an issue.

Comment: thank you sir, maybe sometime i will try your way. Now still dont understand :D

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all.
I did a litte change in my code, temporary i will use this code

```
Timer NewTimer;
int secval;
int tsecs;
...

secVal = int.Parse(BoxSecond.Text);
tsecs = secVal;
NewTimer= new Timer(1000);
NewTimer.Elapsed += NewCounter;

private void TStartStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    NewTimer.Start();
}

private void NewCounter(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    TimeNow= DateTime.Now;
    if (TimeBefore != null)
    {
        if (TimeNow.Second - TimeBefore.Second == 2)
        {
            tsecs--; 
            ...
            //Invoke for label
        }
        else if (TimeNow.Second - TimeBefore.Second == 0)
        {
            tsecs++;
            ...
            //Invoke for label
        }
    }
    TimeBefore = DateTime.Now;
    ...

    if(tsecs != 0)
    {
        tsecs--;
        //Invoke for label
    }
    else if(tsecs == 0)
    {
        tsecs = secVal;
        tsecs--;
        //Invoke for label
    }
}
```

More accurate than before